# What is the equivalent of localhost in Debian using nginx?

Tags: nginx, webserver

Every nginx config guide I find is about setting up the server for, say, example.com. But I don't have a domain name, and I want to set up a local DNS, something like localhost in Windows with Apache that comes with XAMPP. I want to create two ports, which is I believe server blocks in nginx. One of the ports is for api, one of the ports is for the frontend. I have created two files:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/chubak.conf:

```
server {
        listen 85;
        server_name chubak.com;
        access_log /srv/logs/vue.access.log;
        error_log /srv/logs/vue.error.log;
        gzip_static on;
# root /srv/default;
        root /var/www/chubak.com/html;
        index index.html;
        location / {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
```

And /etc/nginx/conf.d/api.chubak.conf:

```
server {
        listen 180;
        server_name api.chubak.com;
        access_log /var/www/api.chubak.com/logs/api.access.log;
        error_log /var/www/api.chubak.com/logs/api.error.log;
        root /var/www/api.chubak.com/html;
        index index.php index.html;
        client_max_body_size 128M;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            gzip off;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
        }
```

And I've created index.html files in the /var/www/site/html folder, but I don't know how to access them. As I said, the tutorials always assume that you have a domain name pointed to your server.

Comment: If you have nothing else (no other sever blocks in nginx) listening to those ports, then http://localhost:85/ and http://localhost:180/ should work, or assuming the IP address of this system is 192.168.1.2: http://192.168.1.2:85/ and http://192.168.1.2:180/ should also work.

Answer (score 0):

The localhost file for debian-based systems is `/etc/hosts`.  Just add a line after the final `127.0.0.1` line with something like this (use the IP address most appropriate):

```
127.0.0.1    chubak.com
127.0.0.1    api.chubak.com
```